# javascript sort function to ember js function

Tags: javascript, sorting, ember.js

I have a javascript function that i want to convert to ember js. For an app (http://www.wilhelminaschool.eu/app2) This function sort a json file on a specific date item "mbwpc-start" and only show the items from today to the future and older items not showed.

Ho i convert this to an ember js function?

```
function showAgenda() {
var wpAPI = 'http://www.wilhelminaschool.eu/api/?json=get_recent_posts&include=id,title,custom_fields&count=150&post_type=mbwpc_event';
$.getJSON(wpAPI, function(result) {

    // first, you must sort your items by the desired criteria, 
    // mbwpc-start descending
    result.posts.sort(function(left, right) {
        return parseInt(right["custom_fields"]["mbwpc-start"]) - parseInt(left["custom_fields"]["mbwpc-start"]);
    });

    var today = new Date();
    //today = today.toDateString(); // "Thu Dec 19 2013"                
    today = today.getTime(); // "Thu Dec 19 2013"               
    var itemCount = 0;
    $.each(result.posts.reverse(), function(i, item) {

        // the date of the calender item
        var postDate = new Date(item["custom_fields"]["mbwpc-start"] * 1000);
        //if ( postDate.toDateString() == today ) {
        if (postDate.getTime() >= today) {
            var html = '<li><h3>' + item.title + '</h3><p>' + postDate.getDate() + '-' + (postDate.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + postDate.getFullYear() + '</p></li>';
            $("#list").append(html);
            // Count, and break the loop if necessary
            if (++itemCount >= 10)
                return false; // break the loop
        }
    });
    $("#list").listview('refresh');
}); // end getjson

} // end function
```

Comment: "Convert to Ember" is a bit vague-- this code does quite a few things- ajax call, sort, render output...  Normally, Ember apps separate these concerns into a model, view and controller.  Try reading the Ember guides and that should help you understand the building blocks: http://emberjs.com/guides/

Comment: heidenmanmedia, here's a template Emberjs.jsbin.com for playing around